My Google Cloud app has been under review for 9 months now
I am confused as to why my app in Google Cloud is still in the verification process. When I applied for the review, they said it would take about 4-6 weeks, but the review has been going on for 9 months.
Could you give me some advice?
Thank you in advance.


Most likely Google sent you an email that you did not respond to (SPAM folder, etc.). Make a change that requires re-verification to start the process over.

The app verification process should only last for 11 weeks or less.
You should follow-up with the OAuth review team directly via the emails you received [1]. Another route that you can do is to buy a support package from Google Cloud and create a support ticket.
[1]. https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/13461325
